# How to fix the org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error

Tags: java, selenium

While running the below code, I am observing `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error` exception.

I am not able to understand why this error occurs even I am using simple driver initialization code.

I am using Eclipse Mars 2.

I used the following code:

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;

    public class APP {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\CDS\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
            try {
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println(e);
            }   
        }
    }
```

Returns this error

[image]

Please guide me to the way to fix it.

Comment: chrome driver version is 2.30. Are you using latest chrome browser?

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 58.19.3029.110

Comment: It's weird... The code looks good. Can you try adding some implicit wait and try? Also, try downloading chromedriver 2.29 and check

Comment: Just tried chromedriver 2.29, still same error.

Comment: You also need to set the path to the driver executable..System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://home/santhoshkumar/Softwares/Selenium/drivers/chromedriver.exe");

Comment: Tried that as well still same error

Comment: I have updated the code and error image.

Comment: I am not sure but just a thought. Before using driver.get can you add some implicit wait and check.

Comment: Tried that as well. the error occurs while executing WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Your code seems to be okay. I guess check the chrome driver compatibility or download the latest chrome driver and check the issue again. Your chrome browser version and chrome driver should be compatible with each other.

Comment: i did check already but the problem remains. chromedriver 3.0 is compatible with the chrome Version 58-60 and mine is Version 58.19.3029.110

Answer (score 0):

It seems `ChromeDriver` is not able to use default `ChromeOptions`.
You can use below code to initialize the `WebDriver`.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

    public class APP {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\CDS\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
            try {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println(e);
            }   
        }
    }
```

> Let me know the status, whether it works for you or not.

Comment: Still same error on line WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Comment: Are you importing only required imports, don't import using .* ? import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;